# list comprehension where list itself is None

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a way for me to deal with the case where the list my_list itself can be None in 
the list comprehension:

```
[x for x in my_list]
```

I tried this:

```
[x for x in my_list if my_list is not None else ['1']]
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is the list `None` or an item in the list?

Comment: Thanks, Moses, but that is a different question, dealing with list *elements* that are None.  My question pertains to the case where the *list* itself is None.

Comment: If you are fine with an empty list having the same effect as `None`, you may simply do `my_list or []`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
>>> my_list = None
>>> [x for x in my_list] if my_list is not None else ['1']
['1']
```

The change here is moving the ternary statement outside of the list comprehension.

Alternatively, if we add some parens, we can keep the ternary statement inside the list comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = None
>>> [x for x in (my_list if my_list is not None else ['1'])]
['1']
```

Comment: Isn't `[x for x in my_list]` the inefficient way of writing `list(my_list)`?

Comment: @spectras Yes. My interpretation is that `x for x` is a stand-in for some other processing that the OP intends but does not want us to focus on.  His focus was on making the ternary statement work.

Comment: Yes, that's right John1024.  Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equivalent to making a copy of the list if it is not None else setting whatever to `["1"]`:

```
 whatever = my_list[:] if my_list is not None else ['1']
```

But I have a feeling what you really want is maybe a single `if my_list is None`:

```
if my_list is None:
     my_list = ['1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is the following:

```
[x for x in my_list or ['1']]
```

However your code is almost correct: you have just to take into account of operator priorities by adding a couple of parenthesis:

```
[x for x in (my_list if my_list is not None else ['1'])]
```